# IO streams in fork()'ed process

Tags: c, linux, console, io, fork

The following example code executes, but output from the forked process is not readable: nothing is shown on console until I press enter, and then "Read failed!" shows.

The question is: why is that, and how can I interact with `stdin` and `stdout` from the `fork()`'ed process?

```
/* example1.c */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (!pid) {
        // child

        char s[64];
        printf("Enter something: ");
        char *res = fgets(s, 64, stdin);
        if (!res) {
            printf("Read failed!\n");
        } else {
            printf("You entered: %s", s);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

Another example of strange behavior of IO streams:

```
/* example2.c */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (!pid) {
        // child

        char *argv[] = {
            "-c",
            "/home/user/echo.sh",
            NULL
        };

        execv("/bin/sh", argv);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`echo.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Enter something: " INPUT
echo "You entered $INPUT"
```

This one returns

```
Enter something: /home/user/echo.sh: line 3: read: read error: 0: Input/output error
You entered
```

**Update 2:**

Looks like this code does exactly what's needed:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid = vfork();
    if (!pid) {
        // child
        system("/home/user/echo.sh");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The solution was to replace `fork` with `vfork`. I just don't know why is this one working...

Comment: Maybe because the parent exits before the child is done?

Comment: @0A0D: thanks, this seems to be the case, and the problem may be easily resolved by using `system()` call instead of `fork`/`execv`. But how do I start an executable in a separate process inheriting IO streams? I mean, I need to be able to kill parent process whenever I want, without waiting child to exit.

Comment: @Andy - `vfork` suspends the calling process until the child terminates.  This is exactly the same as calling `wait` in the parent process.

Comment: While `vfork()` suspends the parent until the child exits or execs on current Linux, it's not guaranteed to do it, and in fact there have been implementations of vfork that were `#define vfork fork`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `wait(2)`.  As in

```
/* example1.c */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int status;
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (!pid) {
        // child

        char s[64];
        printf("Enter something: ");
        char *res = fgets(s, 64, stdin);
        if (!res) {
            printf("Read failed!\n");
        } else {
            printf("You entered: %s", s);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (wait(&status) != pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But what I need is to run en external program in background, without waiting for it to finish. But, as @0A0D already mentioned, your solution indeed prevents streams from closing until child process is finished.

Comment: Or, just call `_exit(0)` instead of `wait()`.

Comment: @Maxim: Can't do that: there might be a lot of other code executed between `fork()`'ing and exiting from parent, so calling `_exit`, which doesn't handle a lot of stuff that `exit` does, seems impossible.

Comment: @Andy - So you want to run a program that spawns a _sibling_ process and then exits while the sibling process continues to run?

Comment: @Seth - yep, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your child process is now in an orphaned process group, where no process is a direct child of the shell (who is supposed to do job-control).

**Orphaned process group:** Process group which doesn't have at least a member who *has a parent not in the process group but within the same session* (~ is a direct child of the shell).

While the parent and child are both running, the situation is like this:

```
$ ps fax -o pid,pgid,sid,ppid,tty,stat,time,cmd
27177 27177 27177 32170 pts/6    Ss   00:00:00  |   \_ /bin/bash
 4706  4706 27177 27177 pts/6    S+   00:00:00  |       \_ ./ex1
 4707  4706 27177  4706 pts/6    S+   00:00:00  |           \_ ./ex1
```

There are two processes, 4706 and 4707 on process group 4706. 4706 is a child of 27177, which is in the same session (27177), but different process group (27177): it's the shell that deals with job control for process group 4706.

When the parent dies, the situation is like this:

```
$ ps fax -o pid,pgid,sid,ppid,tty,stat,time,cmd
27177 27177 27177 32170 pts/6    Ss+  00:00:00  |   \_ /bin/bash
 4664  4663 27177     1 pts/6    S    00:00:00 ./ex1
```

There is only one process, 4664, in process group 4663, and its parent (init) isn't on the same session. The shell cannot deal with job control for this process group, therefore, `read()` and `write()` get `EIO`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on UNIX/Linux, when stdout goes into console it is line-buffered. That is, you don't see any output until you do either:

- `fflush(stdout)`
- `prinf("\n")`
- stdout buffer overflows.

When stdout goes somewhere else (like pipe of file) it is fully-buffered, that is, `printf("\n")` does not flush the buffer.

Comment: Well, that doesn't solve problem with error reading from `stdin`.

Comment: The first step is to check the error code in `errno` when reading fails.